# youtube api XmlWriter$Namespace Exception

Tags: java, youtube-api

I am using the youtube api to upload videos. When I initialize YoutubeService throw me this exception "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gdata.data.ExtensionProfile.declareAdditionalNamespace(Lcom/google/gdata/util/common/xml/XmlWriter$Namespace;)V. I've searched on google but not able to find any related links.

```
String client_id = "7598..com";
String developer_key = "AI39si6..";
**YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(client_id,developer_key);**
service.setUserCredentials("email","password");
```

The Jar files used in the application are : 
com.google.common.source_1.0.0.201004262004.jar.

com.google.gdata-contacts-1.41.5.w1.jar.

gdata-core-1.0-1.41.5.jar.

javax.mail-1.3.3.01.jar.

gdata-youtube-2.0.jar.

gdata-media-1.0.jar.

gdata-client-1.0.jar.

gdata-maps-2.0.jar.

google-collect-1.0.jar.

can anyone suggest if am missing anything ?